# python, remove characters from a string in a list

Tags: python, string, list

Hello I would like to remove the time from this list of dates generated by an API:

```
['2020-07-31 00:00:00.000', '2020-04-30 04:00:00.000', '2020-01-28 05:00:00.000', '2019-10-30 04:00:00.000', '2019-07-30 04:00:00.000', '2019-04-30 04:00:00.000', '2019-01-29 05:00:00.000']
```

I want the list to look like this:

```
['2020-07-31', '2020-04-30', '2020-01-28', '2019-10-30', '2019-07-30', '2019-04-30, '2019-01-29']
```

The thing is I have no idea how to do this task and would like some help.

Comment: Hmm, shot in the dark but does this api involve pandas in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the strings and use the first value of that split in a comprehension

```
dates = [date.split()[0] for date in dates]
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it - assuming that orig is your original list

```
new_list = [item.split()[0] for item in orig]
```

This builds a new list from the original - by splitting each item in the original on whitespace, and then taking the first item in that split entry.